# Sql Subquery parent child relation multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, subquery

I have the below query which works fine and retrieves the right value.

```
 select col1,sum(s1tot+s2tot-s3tot) as 'value'
 from mtable1 maintable1
 left outer join

 (select sum(s1*t1) s1tot from subtable1
 where
 period <200
 ) as t1 on maintable1.id=t1.id
 left outer join
(select sum(s2*t2) s2tot from subtable2
 period <200) as t2 on maintable1.id=t2.id
 left outer join
 (select sum(s3*t3) s3tot from subtable3
 period <200
 ) as t3 on maintable1.id=t3.id

 where
 ---
 group by

 having sum(s1tot+s2tot-s3tot)  <> 0
```

I want to achieve results where value to be split , the value by period. I need to include period in each subquery and should retrieve in the outer/top query

```
 select col1,sum(s1tot+s2tot-s3tot) as 'value',period
 from mtable1 maintable1
 left outer join

 (select sum(s1*t1),period s1tot from subtable1
 where
 period <200
 group by period
 ) as t1 on maintable1.id=t1.id
 left outer join
 (select sum(s2*t2) s2tot,period from subtable2
 period <200
 group by period) as t2 on maintable1.id=t2.id
 left outer join
 (select sum(s3*t3) s3tot,period from subtable3
  period <200
 group by period
 ) as t3 on maintable1.id=t3.id

 where
 ---
 group by

 having sum(s1tot+s2tot-s3tot)  <> 0
```

Comment: you can use `STUFF` and `FOR XML PATH` to achieve your goal, but I did not see `t1.Id` exist (t2.id, t3.id) and is your query complete?

Comment: yes,my query is complete, I need to grab all the records from 3 subtables eventhough they may or may not exist matching rows.